# Can't use delete with spring nativeQuery in H2 database?

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, h2, spring-data

I have two tables/entites:

- **Award:** id,EventType
- **AwardReceived:** award_id,user_gid

I want to delete all awards for user where user_gid='someUserID' and award event type='someType' so here's what I tried:

```
@Modifying
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "delete ar from award_received ar join award aw on ar.award_id=aw.id where ar.user_gid=:user_gid and aw.EventType=:anniversaryEventType")
    public void deleteUserAnniversaryAwardReceiveds(
            @Param("user_gid") String user_gid,
            @Param("anniversaryEventType") String anniversaryEventType);
```

when I tried the exact samq sql in my database it works fine:

```
delete ar from award_received ar join award aw on ar.award_id=aw.id where ar.user_gid='SomeID' and aw.EventType='SomeType'
```

JPA Relation in AwardReceived entity:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "award_id", nullable = false)
private Award award;
```

the error I am getting when executing the spring jpa query is:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement; SQL [delete ar from award_received ar join award aw on ar.award_id=aw.id where ar.user_gid=? and aw.EventType=?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:635)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:106)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:403)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:58)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor$LockModePopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.myapp.service.impl.AwardServiceImpl.generateAwards(AwardServiceImpl.java:201)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at test.myapp.web.controllers.AwardsTest.checkAwards(AwardsTest.java:130)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.NativeSQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(NativeSQLQueryPlan.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.executeNativeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1312)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.executeUpdate(SQLQueryImpl.java:401)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.internalExecuteUpdate(QueryImpl.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractQueryImpl.executeUpdate(AbstractQueryImpl.java:99)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$ModifyingExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:155)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:55)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:95)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:85)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:312)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "AR" not found; SQL statement:
delete ar from award_received ar join award aw on ar.award_id=aw.id where ar.user_gid=? and aw.EventType=? [42102-172]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:169)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:146)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:4824)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:4802)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readSimpleTableFilter(Parser.java:713)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseDelete(Parser.java:735)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:336)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:279)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:251)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:218)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:425)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:374)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1138)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:70)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:267)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$1.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:182)
    ... 47 more
```

please advise how to fix it, thanks.

UPDATE: when I use the HQL query as follows:

```
@Modifying
    @Query("delete from award_received ar where ar.user=:user and ar.award.eventType=:anniversaryEventType")
    public void deleteUserAnniversaryAwardReceiveds(@Param("user") User user,
            @Param("anniversaryEventType") String anniversaryEventType);
```

I am getting following exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement; SQL [delete from myapp.award_received cross join myapp.Award award1_ where user_gid=? and EventType=?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:635)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:106)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:403)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:58)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor$LockModePopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.myapp.service.impl.AwardServiceImpl.generateAwards(AwardServiceImpl.java:201)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at test.myapp.web.controllers.AwardsTest.checkAwards(AwardsTest.java:130)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.exec.BasicExecutor.execute(BasicExecutor.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.executeUpdate(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:413)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(HQLQueryPlan.java:282)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.executeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1289)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.executeUpdate(QueryImpl.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.internalExecuteUpdate(QueryImpl.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractQueryImpl.executeUpdate(AbstractQueryImpl.java:99)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$ModifyingExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:155)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:55)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:95)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:85)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:312)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "DELETE FROM myapp.AWARD_RECEIVED CROSS[*] JOIN myapp.AWARD AWARD1_ WHERE USER_GID=? AND EVENTTYPE=? "; SQL statement:
delete from myapp.award_received cross join myapp.Award award1_ where user_gid=? and EventType=? [42000-172]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:169)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:146)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:181)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.getSyntaxError(Parser.java:484)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:233)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:425)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:374)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1138)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:70)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:267)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$1.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:182)
    ... 49 more
```

I think that this maybe H2/MYSQL issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify Your Query as

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "delete from award_received ar join award aw on ar.award_id=aw.id where ar.user_gid=:user_gid and aw.EventType=:anniversaryEventType")
```

I changed `delete ar from ...`  to `delete from ..`

Update: Problem is the usage of joins in delete query
Corrected Delete Query as

```
delete from award_received  where user_gid=:user_gid and exists (select 1 from award aw where aw.EventType=:anniversaryEventType and aw.id=award_id)
```

so the final code will be:

```
@Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query("delete from award_received where user_gid=:user_gid and exists (select 1 from Award aw where aw.eventType=:anniversaryEventType and aw.id=award_id)")
    public void deleteUserAnniversaryAwardReceiveds(
            @Param("user_gid") String user_gid,
            @Param("anniversaryEventType") String anniversaryEventType);
```

Comment: this also gives same exception.

Comment: now i get the error: `org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "AWARD_RECEIVED" not found; SQL statement:
delete from award_received ar where ar.user_gid=? and exists (select 1 from award aw where aw.EventType=? and aw.id=ar.award_id) [42102-172]`

Comment: try running this SQL directly on your DB..does it give the same error?

Comment: no it gives another error: `SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ar  where ar.user_gid='c0a802b4-403b-1920-8140-3bcea9ae0000' and exists (select ' at line 1 */`

Comment: ,only sample delete `from award_received ar where ar.user_gid='c0a802b4-403b-1920-8140-3bcea9ae0000' ` gives same exception, maybe we can't use aliases in delete query.

Comment: @MahmoudSaleh I Updated Delete Query again in my answer..removed alias for award_recieved...try  that

Comment: ok latest query is correct, it runs fine in sql, but it has another issue with H2 database:  `org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "AWARD_RECEIVED" not found` i will search for it, thanks.

Comment: i had to remove nativeQuery=true for code to work with H2 database

Answer (score 0):

Your DELETE syntax is wrong. Check standard at [13.6 - delete statement: positioned](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt)-(search text, no bookmark available)

Comment: how it's wrong and is working fine in HeidiSQL ? it spring jpa syntax issue.

Comment: Maybe [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17879265/org-h2-jdbc-jdbcsqlexception-schema-myapp-not-found-sql-statement) you can find some other things to check.

Comment: i think that this maybe an issue related to H2/MYSQL integration.